# How to send data (JSON) to an static website

Tags: javascript, c#, html, blazor

Id like to send JSON Data to a static website via an Button.

1. Click on button with href
2. Open Website in PopUp and send data parallel
3. recieve and hold data on the static website

How could this be achieved (or should i use an dynamic website with server for this instead.)

Comment: I think by static you mean a javascript-less website and a dynamic with? Also show your current code and what you have tried so far

Comment: You can send through the url like url?param1=val1&param=val2

Comment: As i described i would like to send a JSON to a serverless/static website

Comment: local storage or maybe something like https://pouchdb.com/ could help?

Comment: do you mean html only when you write "static website" or a side that only allow GET https requests?

Comment: I mean client side websites (webassembly). I found a way btw. i just use localstorage

Comment: Btw for anyone tuning in after all this time. My senior just gave me a shitty description and just said it could be done. He was an embedded dev giving me web dev tickets...